# Diagonalizability of a self-adjoint, diagonalizable operator restriscted to an invariant subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, diagonalization

I would like to know if there is a proof of the following statement that only requires "elementary means" (i.e. not the spectral theorem for Hilbert spaces):

> "Let $H$ be an Hilbert Space and let $K$ be an $\hat X$-invariant closed subspace, where $\hat X$ is a self-adjoint and everywhere-defined operator on $H$. If $\hat X$ admits an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors in $H$ then $\hat X$ also admits an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors in $K$."

The reason behind my question is that I am trying to prove a statement about compatible observables in quantum mechanics and this is the last Lemma I would need.

Comment: Is $\hat{X}$ a bounded (and thus everywhere-defined) operator?  If not, how do you define "$\hat{X}$-invariant"?  Also, is $K$ a closed subspace?

Comment: @RobertIsrael You are right, I should add some details. $K$ is closed and $\hat X$ is everywhere-defined so that by $\hat X$-invariant I mean that $\hat X(K) \subseteq K$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P_K$ be the orthgonal projection on $K$.  The assumption $\hat{X}(K)\subseteq K$ implies $P_K\hat{X}P_K=\hat{X}P_K$.  So
$$P_K\hat{X}={P_K}^*{\hat{X}}^*=(\hat{X}P_K)^*=(P_K\hat{X}P_K)^*={P_K}^*{\hat{X}}^*{P_K}^*=P_K\hat{X}P_K$$
hence $P_K\hat{X}=\hat{X}P_K$.

Let $\{\lambda_i\}_{i\in I}$ be the *distinct* eigenvalues of $\hat{X}$, and $P_i$ the orthogonal projection on the eigenspace of $\lambda_i$.  Then $P_i P_j=0$ for $i\ne j$.

If $P_i x=x$ then $\hat{X}P_K x=P_K\hat{X} x=P_K\lambda_i x=\lambda_i P_K x$.  Hence $P_K(\operatorname{range}(P_i))\subseteq \operatorname{range}(P_i)$.  By an argument similar to above, $P_K P_i = P_i P_K$ for all $i\in I$.  Moreover if $i\ne j$ then $(P_K P_i)(P_K P_j)=P_K P_i P_j = 0$.

Finally,
$$P_K=P_K \mathbf{1}_H=P_K\left(\sum_{i\in I}P_i\right)=\sum_{i\in I}P_K P_i$$
where the sum is in the strong operator topology.